# How to have multiple routes use the same route function in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can use

```
app.get('/:someVar/xxxxx', function(req, res) { /* etc */ });
```

to get someVar by `req.params.someVar`. However, I want both `www.example.com/12345/xxxxx` and `www.example.com/xxxxx` to go into the same `app.get`

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I noticed you don't accept any of the answers to your questions. It's bad etiquette on stackoverflow to ask a question and "abandon" it. You should go through your questions and accept whichever answer (if it exists) helped you to solve your problem. It's a form of closure, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat yourself. Pass an array to `express.js`'s route method:

```
app.route(["/12345/xxxxx", "/xxxxx"])
   .get(function (req, res) { /* etc */ })
```

see [`app.route`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.route) & [`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.get.method)

Answer (score 1):

Assign function to variable

```
var yourFunction = function (req, res) {
...
}
```

And you can use it afterwards as parameter passed to `app.get()`

```
app.get('/:someVar/xxxxx', yourFunction);
app.get('/xxxxx', yourFunction);
```

Comment: talk about [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)